# The table shows in the main window instead of the toplevel window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to let a button show a table in a new window and add a button to that window to destroy itself. The main problem is that the table shows up in the wrong window.
Thanks for help.

I tried to do it myself, but everything I tried doesn't work.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Create new window", 
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 1, column = 3)

    def create_window(self):
        height = 2
        width = 3
        numberA=0
        achievs = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        for i in range(height): #Rows
            for j in range(width): #Columns
                t = tk.Label(text=achievs[numberA], relief=tk.RIDGE)
                t.grid(row=i, column=j)
                numberA = numberA + 1
        t.mainloop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=5, pady=25)
    root.mainloop()
```

As said the table should show in the toplevel window and if possible there should be a button to destroy the toplevel window (I probably can do that part myself tough).

Comment: What the exact version oh python and tkinter you are using ?

Comment: You're not placing it in the Toplevel. How do you think tkinter is supposed to know the widgets go in the toplevel?

Comment: As @BryanOakley said you aren't placing them in the Toplevel, I think `gridVal = tk.Label(ttext=achievs[numberA], relief=tk.RIDGE)
                t.grid(row=i, column=j)` should fix it maybe, I'll try give a full solution if I can understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few mistakes in it, and this seems to be because you might be new to coding, tkinter, or both.

> Firstly you are creating a `Toplevel()` window and assigning it to the variable `t` (`t = tk.Toplevel(self)`) and then when you are creating the grid, instead of placing the grid value into the `Toplevel` window you are assigning the grid value to the variable that hold the `Toplevel` window

This is not how tkinter works, to add an element to a window you give that element its master, in this case the master of the grid value is the variable `t = tk.Toplevel()`

This will change the ``create_window` function to be this:

```py
    def create_window(self):
        height = 2
        width = 3
        numberA=0
        achievs = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        for i in range(height): #Rows
            for j in range(width): #Columns
                gridVal = tk.Label(t, text=achievs[numberA], relief=tk.RIDGE)
                gridVal.grid(row=i, column=j)
                numberA = numberA + 1
```

> Another error you are making is a standard one for new users of tkinter, that is you are creating a new loop for the Toplevel window.

Only one loop (`root.mainloop()`) is needed, and creating this second loop will cause problems, so you can just remove the call to create the second loop (`t.mainloop`)

Changing these things will give you code like this, which should work as you want it to:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Create new window",
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 1, column = 3)

    def create_window(self):
        height = 2
        width = 3
        numberA=0
        achievs = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        for i in range(height): #Rows
            for j in range(width): #Columns
                gridVal = tk.Label(t, text=achievs[numberA], relief=tk.RIDGE)
                gridVal.grid(row=i, column=j)
                numberA = numberA + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=5, pady=25)
    root.mainloop()
```